# Why does my Ruby 'ri' tool not return results in command prompt?

Tags: ruby, rdoc, ri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby 1.9 ri problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587354/ruby-1-9-ri-problem)

When I try to use Ruby's `ri` tool in a command prompt window to get help about classes, methods, etc. it seems to always fail. For example if I type:

```
ri Array
```

I get a message saying:

```
Updating class cache with 0 classes... Nothing known about Array
```

I am using Vista 64 with Ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [i386-mingw32] installed.

What should I do to configure  `ri` to work?

Comment: [Duplicate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587354/ruby-1-9-ri-problem) <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587354/ruby-1-9-ri-problem/1588642#1588642>

Answer (score 76):

Although this question is old, nobody has yet provided a proper solution. I just ran into the same issue, and found the solution:

**If you are using RVM**:

```
rvm docs generate-ri # <- Just the ri docs, much faster
rvm docs generate    # <- Everything (rdoc + ri)
```

More info on managing RVM docs here:
https://rvm.io/rubies/docs

**If not using RVM**:

```
gem install rdoc-data

# Regenerate system docs
rdoc-data --install

# Regenerate all gem docs (rdoc + ri)
gem rdoc --all --overwrite 

# Regenerate all gem docs (ri only)
gem rdoc --all --overwrite --ri --no-rdoc

# Regenerate specific gem doc with specific version
gem rdoc gemname -v 1.2.3 --overwrite
```

Comment: Ruby Documentation now says use `rvm docs generate-ri` for this

Comment: I think `--overwrite` option doesn't need because there's no existing document to overwrite. Another thing because the question was asking `ri` command to work, so we probably don't need `rdoc` so I suggest the command can be `gem rdoc --all --ri --no-rdoc` http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-rdoc

Comment: One more thing, `rdoc-data --install` command does not work on ruby 2.4 (it currently returns `Your ruby version 2.4 is not supported, only 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3`) so I'm still looking for another way to get `ri Array` command working. (for std-lib and core-ruby document)

Comment: in Debian (10.5) the solution for me was `apt-get install ri` .