# ruby 1.9 ri on Windows knows nothing about any classes

Tags: ruby, installation

I'm using Windows XP SP2, and installed Ruby through Ruby 1.9 one click installer. Then when I try to using ri, I get the following response, can anyone help me with my problem?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>ri --version
ri 2.2.2

C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>ri String
Updating class cache with 0 classes...
Nothing known about String

C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>ri
Updating class cache with 0 classes...
No ri data found

If you've installed Ruby yourself, you need to generate documentation using:

  make install-doc

from the same place you ran `make` to build ruby.

If you installed Ruby from a packaging system, then you may need to
install an additional package, or ask the packager to enable ri generation.

C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>
```

By the way, when I try to use gem, I got the following error messages too, anyone can explain it?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>gem --version
1.3.5

C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>gem query --remote

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOMEM)
    Not enough space - <STDOUT>

C:\Documents and Settings\eyang>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RubyInstaller do not bundle RI documentation, as it increased the size of the distribution and the time to install the package.

Instead, we bundled CHM (Windows Help) files for both Core and StdLib API.

This was discussed in the RubyInstaller group and the decision was made on that base.

As for your other point, two things: you need to provide a gem name or part of it, since there are 12K gems in RubyForge.

Also, depending on your console configuration (Latin or something) the Not Enough space error will be related to the terminal itself, not RubyGems.

Answer (score 16):

Go to the same folder where your ruby is installed. Then do:

```
rdoc --all --ri
```

Comment: I ran it and it made ri work for me! :) But I don't know if it downloaded something or just recompiled something... :P [ruby 1.9.2p290, ri 2.5.8, rdoc 2.5.8]

Comment: it regenerates all ri info for all rb files under the root of your installation (gems included) in ~\.rdoc

Comment: I ended up using `rdoc --all --ri-site` so the ri files will be created under the `<ruby>/share/ri` directory rather than in the home directory

Comment: ...however, it does not generate ri data for core + stdlib. For this you have to use the rdoc-data gem as mentioned by @rogerdpack below

Answer (score 9):

windows rubyinstaller doesn't come with the ri for core by default, so install the rdoc-data gem, then it will have it.

Comment: Thanks that helped. It should be mentioned that the above `rdoc --all --ri` does NOT install the ri data for core + stdlib!

Comment: asdf does not install ri for core. and rdoc-data gem does not support Ruby 2.4. Is there any other way to get "ri for core"?

Comment: @kangkyu FWIW appears they come as plain HTML these days: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/QMRd0y-jiD8

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `rvm` try `$ rvm docs generate-ri`

Answer (score 0):

What might be helpful:

1. When I ran `ri.cmd -l` command, it worked, though there were no known Classes/Modules
   [image: CMD screenshot]
2. When I ran `ri.cmd --list-doc-dirs`, I've got:

   ```
   C:/Ruby25-x64/share/ri/2.5.0/system
   C:/Ruby25-x64/share/ri/2.5.0/site
   C:/Users/username/.rdoc</ul>
   ```

   Nonetheless, there was no physical `.rdoc` folder (`C:/Users/username/.rdoc`)
3. Running `rdoc --all --ri` as recommended @GregMoreno did the trick