# Ruby ri at Windows Command prompt does not give correct information

Tags: ruby, ri

Ri seems to be giving results for Rails. Something is not right.
Can anyone help me get useful results from ri. I have an otherwise clean and working up-to-date installation of Ruby (1.9.3) and Rails (3.2.3).
For example if do `ri Range` I get this.

```
Range < Object
(from gem activesupport-3.2.3)

Constants:
RANGE_FORMATS
[not documented]

Instance methods:
include_with_range?
overlaps?
step_with_blockless
to_default_s
to_formatted_s
to_s
```

Comment: This might solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587354/ruby-1-9-ri-problem

Comment: Yes that solved it. Thank you. I found the .chm files. And they appear to be exactly the same information that is at [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/index.html). So I don't really need ri since I'm happy to use the web based information. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Casper pointed me to [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587354/ruby-1-9-ri-problem)
which gave me the information I needed to understand what was happening with ri.
1. ri is not installed automatically since it adds so much size to the install; instead .chm style help files are installed. But these seem to be the same as the help available on line via [RubyDocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/index.html#classes).
2. I think rails may have installed some ri docs, so that when I use ri I do get results for certain queries like the one I listed in my example above.