# Ruby ri file - Nothing known about File error

Tags: ruby, rvm, ri

I tried installing a gem first `gem install rdoc-data`
After it successfully installed, I tried `rdoc-data --install` However, I get the error:
`Your ruby version 2.1.1 is not supported, only 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0`

Does this mean I have to downgrade to Ruby 2.0.0?

---

I tried running `ri File` to read the documentation however all I get is the message: `Nothing known about File`.

Did some research into older Stack Overflow posts and someone `suggested running rvm docs generate` however all I get is `"Currently 'rvm docs ...' does not work with non-rvm rubies.`

Comment: If your ruby was not installed by `rvm`, then `rvm` tag is inappropriate. Also, please specify where then it does come from. Are you on Debian, and installed `ruby` by `apt`? Did you compile the sources yourself? Did you use RubyInstaller for Windows?

Comment: Ruby came installed on my mac and I just had to push a couple updates. I believe I had to install rvm on my own, which I can't remember the entire process. I just found a guide online since I was pretty new to this ruby at the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Ruby 'ri' tool not return results in command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575373/why-does-my-ruby-ri-tool-not-return-results-in-command-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

Install ri documentation first:

```
rvm docs generate-ri
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
gem install rdoc-data
gem rdoc --all --ri --no-rdoc
```

Don't forget to open a new terminal window, then `ri "test"` `ri "if"` etc should thereafter.

These commands came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575373/why-does-my-ruby-ri-tool-not-return-results-in-command-prompt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2726073/5783745)