# ruby RI command will not work

Tags: ruby, cmd, ri

I have installed Ruby 2.2.2 on windows 8 and any ri command will return to me

> "Nothing known about (ie) .string

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: did you search across SO and try the already given solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587354/ruby-1-9-ri-on-windows-knows-nothing-about-any-classes 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625631/nothing-known-about-when-trying-ri-stringupcase-ruby

Comment: Yes! i tried to do that, and nothing changed..