# Why does my `ri` lack documentation of some built-in library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, ri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nothing known about… when trying ri String#upcase Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625631/nothing-known-about-when-trying-ri-stringupcase-ruby)

The version info looks like this:

```
 Hanfeis-MacBook-Pro-2:ruby ad9075$ rvm -v

 rvm 1.17.0 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Hanfeis-MacBook-Pro-2:ruby ad9075$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
Hanfeis-MacBook-Pro-2:ruby ad9075$ ri -v
ri 3.12
Hanfeis-MacBook-Pro-2:ruby ad9075$ ri Math
Nothing known about Math
```

I tried to do `gem rdoc --all`, it gives some `NOTE` and after I execute this command, these library still can't be found by ri.

```
Hanfeis-MacBook-Pro-2:7w7l ad9075$ gem rdoc --all
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from /Users/ad9075/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/rdoc_command.rb:58.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.installed_spec_directories is deprecated, use Specification.dirs. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.installed_spec_directories called from /Users/ad9075/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:47.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
```

Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in called from /Users/ad9075/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:47.

When I try `ri Integer`, instead of returning the document of built-in `Integer`, it returns me the result lke this:

```
= Integer < Object

(from gem activesupport-3.2.9)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
= Instance methods:

  month, months, multiple_of?, ordinalize, year, years
```

I think the problem might be that after I use rvm to switch to a new version of ruby. The **ri** is not configured well that it can't find the path of built-in functions and classes. Does anyone have ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This might be the answer. I'll give a try.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625631/nothing-known-about-when-trying-ri-stringupcase-ruby

Comment: For me it's worse : `$ ri Integer`
Nothing known about Integer
`$ rvm docs generate all`
Currently 'rvm docs ...' does not work with non-rvm rubies.