# "Nothing known about..." message when trying to view documentation

Tags: ruby, rvm, rdoc, ri

I'm quite new to ruby and I'm trying to view Ruby documentation through command prompt (I'm on Windows 7, Ruby version 2.0.0p195). However, no matter which command I try, for example `ri String#upcase`, I always get the message "Nothing known about..."

I have read several posts here but nothing seems to fix the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nothing known about.... when trying ri String#upcase Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625631/nothing-known-about-when-trying-ri-stringupcase-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

With RVM in order to get the system documentation, you can issue the command

```
rvm docs generate-all
```

If you only want the ri documentation, this is what I do:

```
rvm docs generate-ri
```

Comment: All for the want of a full width highlighting? :)  I guess it does communicate the `carriage-return` at the end of those commands.