# Ruby's ri command returns "Nothing known about Array"

Tags: ruby, macos, ri

edit: Question answered by @FrederickCheung . I needed to reinstall ruby this time passing an argument to include docs:

```
brew install ruby --with-doc
```

Question:

I'm new to ruby and trying to get the `ri` command to work in Terminal (iTerm2 on OSX Yosemite). Here's what I've tried so far (everything is pasted from the terminal):

```
ri Array
Nothing known about Array
```

So I google around and tried:

```
gem install rdoc-data

Fetching: rdoc-data-4.0.1.gem (100%)
rdoc-data is only required for C ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.1.

rdoc-data is required for JRuby.

To install ri data for RDoc 4.0+ run:

rdoc-data --install

Successfully installed rdoc-data-4.0.1
Parsing documentation for rdoc-data-4.0.1
Installing ri documentation for rdoc-data-4.0.1
Done installing documentation for rdoc-data after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Tried it again:

```
ri Array
Nothing known about Array
```

Then I tried:

```
rdoc-data --install
Your ruby version 2.2.0 is not supported, only 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0
```

I googled around but the only results I get are for people using `rvm` or trying to disable the docs for rails installations. I installed ruby via `homebrew` if that means anything. I'm not really sure where to go from here, but I'd really like to be able to access the docs via `ri`.

Comment: Probably a duplicate question. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6628309

Comment: "I google around but the only results I get are for people using rvm or trying to disable the docs for rails installations. I installed ruby via homebrew if that means anything." - from original post

Comment: Did you try installing it with the --with-doc option?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I get the same result:

`rdoc-data --install --with-doc option`  
           
`Your ruby version 2.2.0 is not supported, only 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 2.0.0`

Comment: No I meant `brew install ruby --with-doc`

Comment: @FrederickCheung awesome. that worked perfectly. i had no idea ruby was installed w/o docs by default. thanks for the response! is there any way to give you credit for the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brew defaults to disabling installation of documentation.

If you check the [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/ruby.rb) you can see that unless you pass `--with-doc` to `brew install ruby`, it will pass `--disable-install-doc` to the ruby configure script.