# ri Not Working in zsh

Tags: ruby, documentation, zsh, ri

I'm using zsh on Mac OS X.
When I type `ri` followed by a class name everything works fine. However, if I want to look up specific method documentation (e.g. `Array#new`), the shell would tell me `zsh: no matches found: Array#new`

Does this mean the ruby documentation is not completely installed on Mac by default?

Thanks.

Comment: See here for one way to regenerate the Ruby base docs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575373/why-does-my-ruby-ri-tool-not-return-results-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Put Array#new inside single quotes. It's a special operator for zsh

Comment: ok, now that error tells us that the documentation isn't there. I suggest using rvm to install ruby and then running rvm docs generate to generate the ri documentation (it worked for me on OSX lion).