# Why is my Ruby 'ri' tool not working - appears to be a path issue

Tags: ruby

When I try to type:

```
ri File
```

it returns 'Nothing known about file' and pretty much all of the ruby commands do the same thing.

I have found a [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575373/why-does-my-ruby-ri-tool-not-return-results-in-command-prompt) that suggests installing something as follows:

```
gem install rdoc-data
```

but that does not help.  It returns

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
No such file or directory - H:/
```

Notice the H: directory... this is my work computer and it always reinstalls the H: network drive AND I have to disconnect when I want to use Ruby.  I do not have access to this file directory when not in the office.  My hard drive is c:/ I had network/path issues when I was working with Python as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will probably need to give more information about your system configuration/environment.  How are you running Ruby, how did you install it, it looks like you are using Windows.  You may be able to go to where you have Ruby installed and do `rdoc -R` to install the documentation to your system wide location for `ri` documentation.

Comment: Append the output of `gem env` to your question by editing it and pasting the information.